# What's is the meaning of 空しさが勝る?

Tags: translation, meaning

**空しさが勝る**

Is it just "It's fruitless"?

Comment: This question might be better if you added some context.

Answer (score 3):

空しい means "emptiness" or "sense of futility"

勝る means to win or to do better than

Put it together it could mean: "A sense of futility takes over" or more literally, "emptiness wins".  It depends where it is being said.